# Wireless network disabled by hardware switch

Tags: boot, hp, ethernet

My hp Compaq nc8230 is now a secondary boot from windows 7. Both boots have no wifi. On ubuntu, it's saying that the "wifi disabled by hardware switch. I have no idea what's up with it

Can you please help

Comment: It's exactly what it says: *Disabled by hardware switch*. Either a dedicated switch or a key combo.

Comment: Please switch it back on!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check the wireless devices status (example on a good, e.g. unblocked system)

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and if the wireless is blocked, issuing this would unblock it

```
$ rfkill unblock 1
```